# Unable to locate package openssl-dev

Tags: package, root-framework, package-management

I'm trying to install the ROOT CERN packages on linux, using Ubuntu 18.04, and whenever I get into the prerequisites download, with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev cmake g++ gcc binutils libx11-dev libxpm-dev libxft-dev libxext-dev python openssl-dev
```

I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openssl-dev
```

I've tried correcting this by configurating my repository as was suggested in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220039/unable-to-locate-package-libssl-dev-and-i-cant-find-a-solution), yet the problem still persisted.

Would like to know how is it possible to fix this. Thank you.

Edit:

The complete output of the `sudo apt update` command is:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                     
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

I've also tried installing the libssl-dev package with `sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev` and the outcome remains unchanged.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`openssl-dev` is for `RedHat` and `CentOS` systems.
Install `openssl` and `libssl-dev` instead, which works on `Ubuntu` and `Debian`.

```sh
sudo apt-get install openssl libssl-dev
```

Comment: I am sorry, but for Fedora derivates (such as RHEL and CentOS), the package is called `openssl-devel`, not `openssl-dev`. Shortening `-devel` to `-dev` in package names is typically for Debian (and derivates).

Comment: Is it necessary to install the `openssl` package as well as `libssl-dev`? Assuming just a development use case.

Answer (score 1):

Type: sudo apt install libssl-dev
without the version number, that worked for me.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Actually, if you are using https://root.cern/install/dependencies/#ubuntu-and-other-debian-based-distributions, follow the instructions for Debian.

Comment: The easiest way to install root on Ubuntu is with snap:
https://snapcraft.io/install/root-framework/ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

May you can install it by using def command (if it's available!)

eg.: `sudo dnf install openssl-devel`